# Selenium WebDriver - Ruby Assert Statement

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Sorry for the obvious Noob question. I am trying to confirm a certain piece of text is on the page.

HTML:

```
<div id="fmForm">
<a name="Contact"/>
<p class="errormsg">
Please provide a little more information about your enquiry  
<br/>
</p>
```

I am using the following assert statement

```
Then(/^The website should show the following error message "([^"]*)"$/) do |website_error|
  SuccessMessage = driver.find_element(:class,"errormsg")
  website_error.eql? SuccessMessage.text
end
```

From the following step:

```
Then The website should show the following error message "Please provide a little more information about your enquiry"
```

When I run this it passed. If I change the step to:

```
Then The website should show the following error message "Please provide a little more information about your enquiry00000"
```

It also passes. Am I missing something here? I cannot seem to find an ASSERT EXACT Text

Answer (score 0):

Then(/^The website should show the following error message "([^"]*)"$/) do |website_error|
  SuccessMessage = driver.find_element(:class,"errormsg")

> expect(website_error).to eq(SuccessMessage.text)